# log4net:ERROR XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Cannot find Property [MaximumFileSize ] to set object on [log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender]

Tags: c#, unit-testing, log4net

I am trying to debug my unit test however i am getting an error regarding the log4net

Please see error message below.

> Message: TestFixtureSetUp failed in WcfServiceCFPaymentPlanTest
>
> log4net:ERROR XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Cannot find Property
>   [MaximumFileSize ] to set object on
>   [log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender] log4net:ERROR
>   XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Cannot find Property [MaximumFileSize ] to
>   set object on [log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender]

this is the log the log for net from my app.cofig file

```
  <log4net>
    <appender name="rollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender,log4net">
      <param name="File" value="Logs/RedDesktop_LogFile.log" />
      <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
      <param name="RollingStyle" value="Size" />
      <param name="MaximumFileSize " value="10MB" />
      <param name="DatePattern" value="_yyyyMMdd" />
      <param name="StaticLogFileName" value="true" />
      <param name="MaxSizeRollBackups" value="10" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout,log4net">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c : %m%n" />
      </layout>
  </appender>
```

Comment: `MaximumFileSize ` has a space that shouldn't be there.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I fixed the space but this is still an issue

Comment: Isn't the format: `<MaximumFileSize value="100KB" />` and same for the other properties?